# Android , exiting / pausing application, how to destroy thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have an android application with a background thread that contains a socket connection for sending/receiving data from a server.

If my application ends (back button, etc) or is paused (Home button, calling other app), what is the best way of dealing with this background thread?

I have seen 2 ways:

- Call `Thread.setDaemon(true)` after creation and before starting the thread
- Override `onStop()`, `onPause()`, or `onDestroy()`

I just want to ensure that my application doesn't hang or have other strange behavior.

edit:

Also, what's the best solution to close the socket? Do I close it and the inputStream as well? Is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a signal variable of some sort: doing something like

```
public void run(){
while(!stopped){
  // do work
}

// clean up

return;
}
```

And then in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` set stopped to true. You'll need to make sure you clean up behind yourself as well, and if you need to re-start the thread you do so in `onResume` or `onCreate`.

Comment: The thread is not always working on the background.. it's called eventually, and then does his work until finish... 
I need to clean it well if something happens while I am on the middle of some work... Because the thread has access to a socket connection, I think the thread can't be interrupted without ending this socket. 
Not sure of the best way though..

Comment: Yeah, if the process gets completely killed you're kinda out of luck there. I'm uncertain if the process kill invokes ANY of the lifecycle methods, but you could put a `join` on the Thread object after you set `stopped` to true and then wrap all the socket work with a `finally` clause that closes up the socket and does whatever other cleanup work you need.

Comment: Hey Femi.. care to develop on that? Some coding maybe, please?